# Cannot get CoreNLP models files from JBoss Fuse ESB

Tags: apache-felix, jbossfuse, maven-bundle-plugin, stanford-nlp

I have a problem with [CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) using in JBoss Fuse ESB. I installed CoreNLP with it's models on ESB by

```
install wrap:mvn:edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.6.0
install wrap:mvn:edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.6.0//models-english
```

Then, when my module tries to use `models-english` I have error log message

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:485)[275:org.opengravity.camel.nlp:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:765)[275:org.opengravity.camel.nlp:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    ... 69 more
```

I tried to solve this problem by `maven-bundle-plugin` configurations

```
<Embed-Dependency>stanford-corenlp</Embed-Dependency>
```

but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Not all JARs are OSGi compliant. Especially if they try to load resources from the classpath. You can try to enable dynamic import on the bundles by running `dev:dynamic-import XXX` where XXX is the bundle id.

Comment: Thank you, Claus. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I install two modules

```
install wrap:mvn:edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.6.0
install wrap:mvn:edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/3.6.0//models-english
```

and then, as it was advised by Claus Ibsen, I enabled dynamic import on the first bundle `dev:dynamic-import XXX` where `XXX` is the `stanford-corenlp-3.6.0` bundle id. It solved my problem.